# Windows Phone Mango vs Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows Phone development. When I searched on the web looking for code samples for windows phone, sometimes I saw there were projects for Windows Phone Mango. Would someone tell me the difference between Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone Mango?

Comment: The difference in what? Bugs solved? New features? Differences in programming an app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mango was indeed the codename for the Windows Phone 7.5 update. There are a lot of new APIs and features in Windows Phone 7.5 and it brought with it a new SDK (version 7.1). Apps targeting the Windows Phone 7.0 SDK work just fine under 7.1 but apps targeting the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK require the Mango update to run.

[The Windows Phone site](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/start/whats-new-in-windows-phone.aspx) lists the new features in the Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango update) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516%28v=vs.92%29) lists the API changes between the 7.0 SDK and the 7.1 SDK.

Comment: I would also add that even though apps developed under the 7.0 SDK will work in the 7.5 OS and not vice versa, do not target the 7.0 version, because phones not upgraded to 7.5 can no longer download apps from Marketplace, so you will not be gaining any untargeted users, but you will be losing out on lots of nice features.  Download the 7.1 SDK, and target the 7.5 phones.  Now why in the world didn't Microsoft make the SDK version the same as the phone version???

Answer (score 0):

Mango was the code name for Windows Phone 7.5. The only difference you're going to see if perhaps some updated code samples with Mango tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing for you to worry about.
whatever works for pre-mango will work on mango.
therefore most code will works.

and you would only develop for 7.5 aka mango because all existing phone is upgrade-able to mango and phone running 7.0 won't be able to access the marketplace as microsoft had forced everyone to upgrade to 7.5